# syntax error, unexpected T_PRIVATE - Magento

Tags: php, function, magento, magento-1.7

My problem is with two functions :

```
<?php
private function getAttributes() {
$attributesInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
    ->setEntityTypeFilter('4') 
    ->addSetInfo()
    ->getData();

$attr = array();
$currStoreViewId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
foreach($attributesInfo as $attribute):
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load($attribute['attribute_id']);
    if (!$attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront()) continue;
    $labels = $attribute->getStoreLabels();
    if (isset($labels[$currStoreViewId])) $label = $labels[$currStoreViewId];
    else $label = $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
    $attr[ $attribute->getAttributeCode() ] = $label;
endforeach;
return $attr;
}

public function getProductAttributList($_product) {
$pid = $_product->getId();
if (empty($pid)) return false;
$attributes = $this->getAttributes();
if (count($attributes)>0) $html = '<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">';
else return false;
foreach($attributes as $attrcode => $attrlabel) {
    $value = $_product->{'get'.$attrcode}();
    if ($attrcode=='weight') continue;
    if (empty($value)) continue;
    if (is_numeric($value)) $value = $_product->getAttributeText($attrcode);
    $html .= '<tr><td style="width:50%; padding:0 10px 0 0;"><strong>'.$attrlabel.'</strong>
</td><td style="padding:0; width:50%;">'.$value.'</td>';
}
return $html.'</table>';
}
?>
```

I still get the error : syntax error, unexpected T_PRIVATE. Can anyone help me solve this ? 
I have the same problem with the public function.

Comment: You're defining these functions as `private`, but visibility keywords like `public`, `protected` and `private` are only valid inside a class, and I see no class here

Comment: now i get another error! : Cannot redeclare getAttributes() (previously declared here : $attributesInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection') !!

Comment: @aelhobbi how do you import file with this functions? if you use `include` or `require` change it to `include_once/require_once`

Comment: @AlexanderZhovtobryuh yop! that did the trick ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function can't be public/protected/private. This modifiers can be applyed only for class methods.